# Organize multiple websites on Macbook

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

What steps are needed to complete ***adding*** another website to OS X (Lion) ?

I want to have the 2 websites organized in 2 folders under 'Sites', but not sure how to get there. As can be seen in the image below, the MB currently has the 'default' (first) website spread out in Sites. I am concerned that putting this default site into a folder of Sites, call it 'siteA' will cause it to disappear.

These sites are ***not*** hosted on this MB. (OK, well they are, ...) It is being used for the development, viewing and testing within BBEdit.

After the steps below, the URL `http://bella`, replies Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server. (??)

Suggestions welcomed. Thanks in advance.

So far, I've added or amended:

```
-- private/etc/hosts (added the following)
127.0.0.1 bella

-- private/etc/apache2/http.conf (uncommented 2nd line)
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

-- /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf (added 2 VirtualHost blocks)
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/dolan2go/Sites/Bella"
   ServerName bella
</VirtualHost>
```

The directory structure of my Macbook currently looks like:

[image: Directory structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to make a few modifications to get this to work. With the desire to have folders 'FirstSite' & 'Bella' in the 'Sites' folder. (My User directory structure has been altered because of a HD & SSD hardware mod)

1. Amend the hosts.conf file to: (last 2 lines - see note below)

   ```
   127.0.0.1 bella.local
   127.0.0.1 firstSite.local
   ```
2. Uncomment the line to use the vhosts.conf file (as in original question)
3. Amend the httpd-vhosts.conf to:

   ```
   # Localhost first
   <VirtualHost *:80>  
      DocumentRoot "/Volumes/HDD 1/<username>/Sites"
      ServerName localhost
   </VirtualHost>

   # local test Sites
   <VirtualHost *:80> 
      DocumentRoot "/Volumes/HDD 1/<username>/Sites/FirstSite"
      ServerName firstSite.local
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:80> 
      DocumentRoot "/Volumes/HDD 1/<username>/Sites/Bella"
      ServerName bella.local
   </VirtualHost>

   # Allow from localhost only or other directives
   <Directory "/Volumes/HDD 1/<username>/Sites/FirstSite">
       Order Deny,Allow
       Allow from 127.0.0.1
       Deny from all
   </Directory>

   <Directory "/Volumes/HDD 1/<username>/Sites/Bella">
       Order Deny,Allow
       Allow from 127.0.0.1
       Deny from all
   </Directory>
   ```

Now I can access the local version of both sites with `http://bella.local` & `http://firstSite.local` (I decided to add the local to help distinguish between the local and remote versions.)

A reply by twtwtw 3/4 down the page at [Local Web Server for Lion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3216810?start=0&tstart=0) really helped clear the issue.